# Run Chrome From a Batch File as a Specific User

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I'm trying to write a simple batch file to open Chrome with disabled web security, and using a specific person/user profile.

So far, I have tired:

```js
start chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Which opens chrome with disabled security,. but I can't find a flag specifying which user profile will be opened

Now it simply opens chrome with the last user to log-out. Does anyone know how to open chrome as a specific user profile?

Comment: You can find list of all available commands [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: I think `Firefox` supports profiles but not chrome.Eventually you can try selenium chromedriver.exe which can work with some pre-defined settings....

Comment: Don't use the "code snippet" formatting for anything but JavaScript. The "Run code snippet" buttons do nothing for batch files. Also, I feel this is a bit off topic because you're really looking for a chrome command line flag, not help writing a batch file. The best place for this might be SuperUser.

Comment: The site wouldnt let me post this question when putting the code in simple quotes, only when i marked it as <code> it worked.

anyway, thanks for the remarks. I'll keep it in mind.